# cross correlation in matlab without function

Tags: c, matlab, signal-processing, cross-correlation

Im trying to plot a normalized cross correlation in matlab however im not sure if the code is correct because i Keep getting an error saying "In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same." please how can i correct this?

```
%cross correlation
if  length(s1_filtered)>length(s2_filtered)
    pad = length(s1_filtered)-length(s2_filtered);
    s2_filtered = [s1_filtered zeros(1,pad)];

elseif length(s1_filtered)<length(s2_filtered)
    pad = length(s2_filtered)-length(s1_filtered);
    s1_filtered= [s2_filtered zeros(1,pad)];
end  


out_length = length(s1_filtered);
out = zeros(1,out_length);
denom = zeros(1,out_length);

for k = 1:out_length
    out(k) = s1_filtered*s2_filtered';
   s2_filtered = [0 s2_filtered(1:end-1)];
end
for a = 1:out_length
    denom(a) = sqrt(s1_filtered.^2).* sqrt(s2_filtered.^2);
    s2_filtered = [0 s2_filtered(1:end-1)];
end

crossc=out(k)/denom(a);

figure(8);
plot(crossc);
title('CROSS CORRELATION OF S1 AND S2');
```

Comment: it seems that in this line `denom(a) = sqrt(s1_filtered.^2).* sqrt(s2_filtered.^2);` you're assigning a vector into a scalar

Comment: How can I correct this please ?

Comment: You are probably interested in the [dot product](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html).